# What to do if what my Lead say is different from what others expect from me

Tags: teamwork, leadership

I started a new job, I really liked it and it was ok. I've been doing cool stuff for 5 months. Now I started noticing strange things, I've been working closely with few people from others departments (design) to provide them with tools to make their job easier/ possible. Now they are coming to complain, because I did not implement a feature I didn't ever know existed. It looks to me there is a communication problem. So far I've been programming on all the features the lead asked to me and I provided support to other teams to bugfix the things I've made.

It is strange to me people expect things I've never been told of. I already asked my Lead if I have to do that stuff, he was vague about that, when I speak face to face he says I didn't have to do that stuff and he put me working in other tasks. However I have a bad feeling about that. Why did other teams not know I'm not the designed person for certain tasks?

It looks like there is a organization problem, the lead is young and have been a Lead for just 3 months.

How can I resolve that in the best way for everyone? First of all I don't want to be in trouble because of organization problems. But I truly want to help the Lead to stay in that position and in general to resolve troubles since I like that job.

Comment: You just do the work you are assigned to do to the best of your abilities, and don't worry about what people say. People will say all sorts of nonsense, you can't make everyone happy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So person X complains that you didn't implement a feature that X expected or hoped or wished to be implemented, while you didn't ever hear about this.

You obviously do what your manager or your team lead asks you to do. So unless your manager told you "do anything you need to make X happy", then you are not implementing this feature.

On the other hand, you don't want others in the company to get the impression that you are incompetent, lazy, not bothered etc. So your reply to X is: "I am sorry to hear that you expected this feature, and it is not implemented. Unfortunately, this is the first time I heard of this feature. If it is important to you, then you need to request this feature from my manager or team lead. I will be only too happy to implement it if they ask me to do that. However, I will not be able to implement this without being told to by my manager or team lead".

Answer (score 8):

This is common and easy to deal with, any complaints etc,. you refer to your lead to worry about, and you just concentrate on the tasks assigned to you by the person actually authorised to assign them.

So long as you're doing your assigned tasks competently, you'll be fine, mind reading isn't usually part of the job.